# She is lying on the bed and got hit by a car. - how would you interpret this?

Tags: meaning

**Example 1**

> She got hit by a car and is lying on the bed.

**Example 2**

> She is lying on the bed and got hit by a car.

I know Example 1 is acceptable. However, I wonder if I can change the order as I did for Example 2.

I feel like Example 2 sounds like her lying on the bed and getting hit by a car have no correlation and sounds like two different events. Maybe she is lying on the bed because of an illness and has nothing to do with the car accident. Is my understanding correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first sentence is a clear cause-and-effect story.

The second sentence almost sounds like she was lying in bed when she got hit by a car, except that it says, "She ***is*** lying on the bed and she ***got*** hit by a car", so the tenses make that impossible. So, without that possibility, it sounds like two completely unrelated clauses joined with "and" for no good reason. It certainly doesn't sound like a cause-and-effect story.

Answer (score 3):

My response would be

> Wait ... what??

Without further context I'd interpret them as "A car came into her bedroom and hit her." But wait ... what? That seems very unlikely.

So my second assumption was that you had made a mistake, or a joke, or I had misunderstood you, and so I would ask you to explain yourself.

Comment: Although unlikely people do manage to crash vehicles into houses. But I agree with you this is more a question of the physics of everyday life than learning English.